# Kotlin class runs as junit tests even when it is in androidTest package - for Java class it runs normally

Tags: java, android, junit, kotlin, android-testing

I've run into very strange error.

When i try to run test that are in my Kotlin class in androidTest package they are running as test junit mehthods and this error appears:

> Process finished with exit code 1
>   Class not found: "com.someampp.shoppinglistapp.SomeClassTest"Empty test suite.

You can try it for yourself. I am using Android Studio 3.0.1

When i am creating class like this in Java:

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
public class SomeTestClass{
@Test
public void useAppContext() throws Exception {
    // Context of the app under test.
    Context appContext = InstrumentationRegistry.getTargetContext();

    assertEquals("com.myapp.shoppinglistapp", appContext.getPackageName());
  }
}
```

Everything works fine.

But when i convert the Java file to Kotlin:

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)
class SomeTestClass{
@Test
@Throws(Exception::class)
fun useAppContext() {
    // Context of the app under test.
    val appContext = InstrumentationRegistry.getTargetContext()

    assertEquals("com.myapp.shoppinglistapp", appContext.packageName)
  }
}
```

It gives me this error.

Whats wrong?

Answer (score 2):

You need to open [`Run/Debug configurations`](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/rundebugconfig.html) and create one for Android Instrumented Tests instead of Android JUnit.

Comment: But this means, that i will have to manually do it for every test?

Comment: No, you do it once and then press the run (or debug) button next to the configuration dropdown in the toolbar. Or in the Run menu. Or a key combination.

Comment: You сould also look in Android Studio bug tracker and submit this bug if it wasn't reported yet.

Comment: Thanks, i guess it is not, i reported it

Comment: More info/screenshots if anyone is interested in the details of how to accomplish the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53715513/967131